# Implementación API Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, api, webapi

Estoy intentando implementar 2 API's en una sola, para traer la información detallada ya que se usará en una copia de una web

La primer APi es la siguiente, aquí se hace la llamada a las actividades y sus descripciones

```
//** API QUE TRAE ACTIVIDADES CON DATOS DE NOMBRE, DESCRIPCIONES E IMÁGENES **//
public function index(Request $request) {

    $data = array();
    $actividades = Actividad::join('traducciones_palabras', 'actividades.nombre_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
   ->join('categoria_actividades', 'actividades.categoria_apertura_id', 'categoria_actividades.id')
   ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 'lenguajes.id')
    ->where([
      ['actividades.status', '=', 1],
      ['actividades.publicacion_activa',1],
      ['lenguajes.status', '=', 1],
      ['lenguajes.codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
    ])
    ->select(
        'actividades.id','actividades.imagen', 'traducciones_palabras.texto as actividad',
        'lenguajes.codigo', 'actividades.descripcion_traduccion_id', 
        'categoria_actividades.categoria_traduccion_id', 'actividades.pivote_id')
    ->orderBy('actividades.id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    foreach ($actividades as $key => $actividad) {
        $descripcion = Traducciones_palabra::join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 
            'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['traduccion_id', '=', $actividad->descripcion_traduccion_id],
            ['codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
        ])->select('texto')->get();

        $categorias = Traducciones_palabra::join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 
            'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['traduccion_id', '=', $actividad->categoria_traduccion_id],
            ['codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
        ])->select('texto')->get();

   
       $data['actividad'][$key] = [
            'id' => $actividad->id,
            'nombre' => $actividad->actividad,
            'descripciones' => $descripcion[0]->texto,
            'imagen' => $actividad->imagen,
            'categorias' => $categorias[0]->texto,
            'pivote_id' => $actividad->pivote_id,
            'galleria' => []
        ];

        $galleria = CentroConsumo_gallerias::where('pivote_id', 
        $actividad->pivote_id)->select('imagen')->get();

        foreach ($galleria as $key_g => $value_g) {
            $data['actividad'][$key]['galleria'][$key_g] = $value_g;
        }  
    }
    return $data;
}
```

La otra APi es esta, aquí se hace la llamada a horarios

```
public function getApertura(Request $request) {


    $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $first = strtotime('this monday this week');

    $data = array();
    $actividad = Apertura_actividad::join('categoria_aperturas', 'apertura_actividades.tipo_Apertura_id' 
        ,'categoria_aperturas.id')
        ->join('traducciones_palabras', 'categoria_aperturas.categoria_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
        ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', '=', 'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['apertura_actividades.status', 1],
            ['apertura_actividades.actividad_id' , $request->apertura_actividad],
            ['apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio' , date('Y-m-d', $first)],
            ['lenguajes.codigo', $request->code_lenguaje],
        ])
        ->select('traducciones_palabras.texto as apertura', 'apertura_actividades.id as apertura_actividad', 'apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio', 'apertura_actividades.actividad_id')
        ->get();
    

    foreach ($actividad as $key => $value) {

        $dias_aperturas =Dia_aperturas_actividad::join('dias', 'dia_aperturas_actividadades.dia_id', 
            'dias.id')
           ->join('traducciones_palabras', 'dias.dia_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
           ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', '=', 'lenguajes.id')
           ->where([
                ['dia_aperturas_actividadades.apertura_actividade_id', $value['apertura_actividad']],
                ['lenguajes.codigo', $request->code_lenguaje],
              
            ])->get();

            foreach ($dias_aperturas as $key_2 => $value_2) {
            
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['id'] = $value['actividad_id'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['apertura'] = $value['apertura'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['fecha_inicio'] = $value['fecha_inicio'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['actividad_id'] = $value['apertura_actividad'];
                
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['horario'][$key_2]['dia'] = $value_2['texto'];

                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['horario'][$key_2]['hora_inicio'] = $value_2['hora_inicio'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key]['horario'][$key_2]['hora_final'] = $value_2['hora_final'];
                
            } 
    }
    return $data;
}
```

lo que estoy intentando es implementar la segunda APi dentro de la primera en la sección de la $data

```
$data['actividad'][$key] = [
            'id' => $actividad->id,
            'nombre' => $actividad->actividad,
            'descripciones' => $descripcion[0]->texto,
            'imagen' => $actividad->imagen,
            'categorias' => $categorias[0]->texto,
            'pivote_id' => $actividad->pivote_id,
            'galleria' => [],
            'aperturas' => []
        ];
```

en `'aperturas[]'` es donde quiero de alguna manera lograr imprimir los datos de la llamada de la API

---

Hice de pruebas la siguiente

```
//** NUEVA API PARA LLAMADA DE ACTIVIDADES CON HORARIO  **//
public function getAperturaDetails(Request $request) 
{
    $data = array();
    $actividades = Actividad::join('traducciones_palabras', 'actividades.nombre_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
   ->join('categoria_actividades', 'actividades.categoria_apertura_id', 'categoria_actividades.id')
   ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 'lenguajes.id')
   ->join('apertura_actividades', 'actividades.pivote_id','apertura_actividades.actividad_id')
    ->where([
      ['actividades.status', '=', 1],
      ['actividades.publicacion_activa',1],
      ['lenguajes.status', '=', 1],
      ['lenguajes.codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
    ])
    ->select(
        'actividades.id','actividades.imagen', 'traducciones_palabras.texto as actividad',
        'lenguajes.codigo', 'actividades.descripcion_traduccion_id', 
        'categoria_actividades.categoria_traduccion_id', 'actividades.pivote_id')
    ->orderBy('actividades.id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    foreach ($actividades as $key => $actividad) {
        $descripcion = Traducciones_palabra::join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 
            'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['traduccion_id', '=', $actividad->descripcion_traduccion_id],
            ['codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
        ])->select('texto')->get();

        $categorias = Traducciones_palabra::join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', 
            'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['traduccion_id', '=', $actividad->categoria_traduccion_id],
            ['codigo', '=', $request->code_lenguaje]
        ])->select('texto')->get();

       $data['actividad'][$key] = [
            'id' => $actividad->id,
            'nombre' => $actividad->actividad,
            'descripciones' => $descripcion[0]->texto,
            'imagen' => $actividad->imagen,
            'categorias' => $categorias[0]->texto,
            'pivote_id' => $actividad->pivote_id,
            'galleria' => [],
            'aperturas' =>[ 
            ]
        ];

        $galleria = CentroConsumo_gallerias::where('pivote_id', 
        $actividad->pivote_id)->select('imagen')->get();

        foreach ($galleria as $key_g => $value_g) {
            $data['actividad'][$key]['galleria'][$key_g] = $value_g;
        }
        
        $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
        $first = strtotime('this monday this week');

        $aperturas = Apertura_actividad::join('categoria_aperturas', 'apertura_actividades.tipo_Apertura_id' 
        ,'categoria_aperturas.id')
        ->join('traducciones_palabras', 'categoria_aperturas.categoria_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
        ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', '=', 'lenguajes.id')
        ->where([
            ['apertura_actividades.status', 1],
            ['apertura_actividades.actividad_id' , $request->apertura_actividad],
            ['apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio' , date('Y-m-d', $first)],
            ['lenguajes.codigo', $request->code_lenguaje],
        ])
        ->select('traducciones_palabras.texto as apertura', 'apertura_actividades.id as apertura_actividad', 'apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio', 'apertura_actividades.actividad_id')
        ->get();
    
        foreach ($actividad as $key_1 => $value) {

        $dias_aperturas =Dia_aperturas_actividad::join('dias', 'dia_aperturas_actividadades.dia_id', 
            'dias.id')
           ->join('traducciones_palabras', 'dias.dia_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
           ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', '=', 'lenguajes.id')
           ->where([
                ['dia_aperturas_actividadades.apertura_actividade_id', $value['apertura_actividad']],
                ['lenguajes.codigo', $request->code_lenguaje],
              
            ])->get();

            foreach ($dias_aperturas as $key_2 => $value_2) {
            
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['id'] = $value['actividad_id'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['apertura'] = $value['apertura'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['fecha_inicio'] = $value['fecha_inicio'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['actividad_id'] = $value['apertura_actividad'];
                
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['horario'][$key_2]['dia'] = $value_2['texto'];

                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['horario'][$key_2]['hora_inicio'] = $value_2['hora_inicio'];
                $data['horarios_aperturas'][$key_1]['horario'][$key_2]['hora_final'] = $value_2['hora_final'];
                
            } 
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

pero al llamar a la APi `'aperturas[]'` regresa vacío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Join que estoy buscando es el siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM actividades as A Inner Join apertura_actividades as B ON A.pivote_id=B.actividad_id WHERE 1
```

No tengo tanta experiencia en API REST, espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 2):

Te escribiria un comentario, pero no puedo asique lo pongo aqui.

Tras analizar tu codigo, creo que el problema esta en que populas $data de esta forma:

```
$data['actividad'][$key] = [
    'id' => $actividad->id,
    'nombre' => $actividad->actividad,
    'descripciones' => $descripcion[0]->texto,
    'imagen' => $actividad->imagen,
    'categorias' => $categorias[0]->texto,
    'pivote_id' => $actividad->pivote_id,
    'galleria' => [],
    'aperturas' =>[],
];
```

Ahi inicializas aperturas como array vacio, hasta aqui todo bien.

Mas tarde tienes el siguiente join:

```
$aperturas = Apertura_actividad::join('categoria_aperturas', 'apertura_actividades.tipo_Apertura_id', 'categoria_aperturas.id')
    ->join('traducciones_palabras', 'categoria_aperturas.categoria_traduccion_id', 'traducciones_palabras.traduccion_id')
    ->join('lenguajes', 'traducciones_palabras.lenguaje_id', '=', 'lenguajes.id')
    ->where([
        ['apertura_actividades.status', 1],
        ['apertura_actividades.actividad_id' , $request->apertura_actividad],
        ['apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio' , date('Y-m-d', $first)],
        ['lenguajes.codigo', $request->code_lenguaje],
    ])
    ->select('traducciones_palabras.texto as apertura', 'apertura_actividades.id as apertura_actividad', 'apertura_actividades.fecha_inicio', 'apertura_actividades.actividad_id')
    ->get();
```

Entiendo que has probado que te devuelve todo esto y que dentro de $aperturas tienes la informacion que quieres. El problema es que despues no utilizas en ningun lado esta informacion que recibes.

En caso de querer la informacion tal cual la recibes en el join tendrias que hacer lo siguiente:

```
 $data['actividad'][$key]['aperturas'] = $aperturas;
```

Yo tambien comprobaria que lo que contiene $aperturas es un array y en caso de que sea asi ejecutar la linea de encima y sino dejarla como array vacio, ya que sino luego tendras problemas si lo tratas siempre como array.

Si por el contrario prefieres hacer un mapeo o algo con la informacion de $aperturas tendrias que hacer algo parecdo a lo que has hecho aqui:

```
foreach ($galleria as $key_g => $value_g) {
    $data['actividad'][$key]['galleria'][$key_g] = $value_g;
}
```

Pero tendrias que cambiar el nombre de las variables por las que corresponda etc...

Comment: Este es el resultado del join `{"horarios_aperturas":[{"id":1,"apertura":"Ma\u00f1ana","fecha_inicio":"2022-04-25","actividad_id":4018,"horario":[{"dia":"Lunes","hora_inicio":"09:00","hora_final":"18:00"}`, ese es el resultado que espero recibir, de ahí tomo algunos datos para imprimirlos en la web,  `$aperturas`, va enlazado con  `$dias_aperturas`, este recibe la info y la ordena en la impresión de los  `$data`

Comment: Entonces entiendo que con lo que te he dicho te sirve, añade al codigo `$data['actividad'][$key]['aperturas'] = $aperturas;` y listo

Comment: El código lo agrego al final del método de `$aperturas`, cierto? o dentro del `foreach`

Comment: Yo lo añadiria justo despues del join que comentabamos de $aperturas @JhonnyEliezer

Comment: Lo agregué, pero me sigue regresando `$aperturas=[]`

Comment: Cuando llamas a la api despues de agregarlo sale `'actividad': [{'aperturas': [] }]` ?

Comment: Así es, cuando se imprime llega de esa manera, utilice `dd($aperturas);` y me llega igual lo siguiente, `Collection {#1839 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135873/discussion-between-jhonny-eliezer-and-adrigo).